# Try to make a for loop that stops at a given letter in a string

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a for loop that stops when it finds the second "e" or "E" in any given string. So far I have come up with this code but the output is wrong. Any ideas would be helpful.

```
mystring <- "R fever"
index <- 1
ecount <- 0 
result <- mystring
while(ecount<2 && index <= nchar(mystring)){
substr(mystring, 1, index) -> result
if(result == "e" || result == "E") {ecount = ecount + 1}
if(ecount == 2) {
sustr(result, 1, index-1)
}
index <- index +1
cat(result)
}
```

Comment: here is an issue `substr(mystring, 1, index) `

Comment: `gregexpr("e|E", mystring)[[1]][2]` to get position of second e or E, you can loop on 1:position

Comment: This somewhat echoes of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are asking for help on an your y solution to an x problem we do not know. What is the larger issue of your situation? Searching a text file? Indexing characters in a data frame column?

Comment: Also: `sustr` should probably be `substr`

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanna stick with that loop:

```
mystring <- "R fever"
index <- 1
ecount <- 0 
result <- mystring
while(ecount<2 && index <= nchar(mystring)){
  substr(mystring, index, index) -> result
  if(result == "e" || result == "E") {ecount = ecount + 1}
  if(ecount == 2) {
    substr(result, 1, index-1)
  }
  index <- index +1
  cat(result)
}
# R feve
```

You only had an issue in `substr(mystring, 1, index)` which should be `substr(mystring, index, index)`.

Otherwise there are simpler options. For example:

```
strsplit(sub('(^[^e]*e[^e]*)e(.*)$', '\\1e_\\2', mystring), "_", mystring)[[1]][1]
# [1] "R feve"
```

Comment: Thx @Gregor, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it helped to get the result R feve. What I need now is it to result in R fev. Its for a project I am working on for class but I cannot get the code right. I need it to be the same format.  @symbolrush

Comment: Just add a `break` statement to the `if(ecount == 2) {}` statement. But that's not really good practice. Or change the `strsplit` to: `strsplit(sub('(^[^e]*e[^e]*)e(.*)$', '\\1_\\2', mystring), "_", mystring)[[1]][1]`